# Qt redirect output from cout to qDebug

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2013

Okay, I'm using MSVS 2013 and Qt(msvc2013+opengl 32bit)

I have main window of application written in Qt and extension dll. Main application writes qDebug(). But extension dll knows nothing about qDebug(), so I'm using std::cout. I've found ugly solution:

```
void Console()
{
    AllocConsole();
    FILE *pFileCon = NULL;
    pFileCon = freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

    COORD coordInfo;
    coordInfo.X = 130;
    coordInfo.Y = 900;

    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coordInfo);
   SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE| ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS);
}
```

And in main I call function `Console()` it gives me black console near my window. It is not very neat and also I want to see events sequentially, but I see them separatly in Application Output and console.

So question is: Is there any way to capture all std::cout output from dll and throw it to Application Output?

Answer (score -2):

You need to redirect the output given by qDebug().

```
static void customMsgHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &, const QString &message)
{
  QString txt;
  switch (type) {
  case QtDebugMsg:
    txt = QString("Debug: %1").arg(message);
    break;
  case QtWarningMsg:
    txt = QString("Warning: %1").arg(message);
    break;
  case QtCriticalMsg:
    txt = QString("Critical: %1").arg(message);
    break;
  case QtFatalMsg:
    txt = QString("Fatal: %1").arg(message);
    abort();
  }

  QFile outFile("log.txt");
  outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);
  QTextStream ts(&outFile);
  ts << txt << endl;
}
```

Then in the main() function after declaring the QAplication

```
qInstallMessageHandler(customMsgHandler);
```

This will make you a trace file were all the qDebug() calls will write on.

I hope this would help

Comment: I believe the question is asking for a solution to redirect `std::cout` to `qDebug()` not how to redirect `qDebug()`.